# O que é um irmão adjacente? No que ele difere de um nó irmão?

Tags: html, css, html5, terminologia, elementos

Um conceito que me deixa confuso ao se falar em HTML é o de ***adjacência***, e de *nós **irmãos***.

Qual a diferença de **irmãos** e  **irmãos adjacentes** ?

Comment: [**Irmão Adjacente**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) => Elemento seguinte do mesmo nível; [**Irmãos Adjacente**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) (ou Adjacente Geral) => Elementos seguinte do mesmo nível.

Comment: como assim seguinte do mesmo nivel ? poderia me explicar um pouco melhor por favor ?obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Segue dois exemplos https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/XYeBxx?editors=1100#0

Comment: Fala Danilo! Blz? Não deixe de marcar a resposta se foi boa. Se não ficou claro ainda, podemos melhorá-la. Abs!

Answer (score 14):

*Irmãos* são elementos que estão no mesmo nível da árvore do DOM:

```
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
<p>p1</p>
```

`div1`, `div2` e `p1` são elementos irmãos, pois estão no mesmo nível.

*Irmão adjacente* (no singular, pois é apenas um) é o elemento que está logo após. No exemplo acima, a `div2` é irmã adjacente da `div1`, e o `p1` é irmão adjacente da `div2`.

Segundo a definição do termo **adjacente**:

> Adjacente é um adjetivo que qualifica algo que está ao lado de, ou
>   seja, junto ou próximo de determinada coisa.

No caso do CSS, é algo que vem LOGO após, até porque o termo *Cascading Style Sheets* (folhas de estilo em cascata) sugere elementos sempre abaixo na árvore, como uma cascata que sempre vai pra baixo. Você não consegue selecionar elementos superiores ou anteriores na árvore (exceto com JavaScript).

Outro exemplo:

```
<div id="pai">
   <div>div1</div>
   <div>div2</div>
</div>
<p>p1</p>
```

Os elementos `div1` e `div2` são irmãos, pois estão no mesmo nível dentro da `div pai`. Já o `p1` agora é irmão da `div pai`, e `p1` é irmão adjacente da `div pai` porque vem logo em seguida e está no mesmo nível na árvore.

No CSS você seleciona os irmãos com o sinal `~` entre os elementos e os adjacentes com `+`.

Selecionar todos os irmãos de `#div1` e coloca a cor vermelha:

```css
#div1 ~ *{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
<p>p1</p>
```

Seleciona o irmão adjacente da `#div1` e coloca a cor vermelha:

```css
#div1 + *{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
<p>p1</p>
```